# Performance tests on iPad 2

Tags: objective-c, performance, ipad

I'm currently conducting a research on computer performance and want to try some tests on iPad 2.

What are the best methods to calculate the execution time of a function in Objective-C?

Also, what are the ways to calculate iPad's FLOPS performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best method for calculating the execution time of any function in the ipad is to use instruments - it uses a very low-overhead mechanism for code instrumentation.

The best method to use for calculating flops performance is to use the [Solution suggested in this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/88357/estimate-flops-in-linux) - If the source code is in C, then it should compile trivially on the iPad.